# Correct use of scale value in indirect addressing

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, addressing-mode

If I have to translate a simple C function with some kind of addressing like this:

```
void f(int *a, int *b, long i){
    a[i] = b[i];
}
```

in System V AMD X86-64 (AT&T standard) assembly, using indirect addressing with `index`, `base` register plus a `scale` value.

So, because there's not any kind of arithmetic on pointer in assembly, the scale value should be `4` for a integer pointer?

Is this code correct?

```
f:
    pushq %rpb           # editor's note: typo for %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movl (%rsi, %rdx, 4), %eax
    movl %eax, (%rdi, %rdx, 4)
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

Comment: Did you try running it? Is it not working?   By the way, you shouldn't assume `int` to be any particular size. Use the types defined in `stdint.h` (e.g. `int32_t`) if you need integers of a particular size.

Comment: The question originally loaded / stored `%rax`.  An edit to change that to `%eax` invalidated point 2 in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't understand why you need to push and pop rbp. It seems you are not changing it...
2. Since a and b are int pointers, I would use eax instead of rax
3. Yes, you need to multiply by 4 when doing calculation of pointer in asm(I assume you are using a machine that thinks sizeof(int)=4. If you are not sure, test it. Or you can use stdint.h with int32_t on your C version for a reliable result.
4. A possible code could be:

   mov       eax, dword ptr [rsi+rdx*4]
    mov       dword ptr [rdi+rdx*4], eax
    ret

I think this code should run with no error. Let me know if something goes wrong here. Thanks.

Good luck!

xiangpisaiMM

Comment: By the way, I am using intel syntax...You may need to modify it to at&t syntax accordingly...

Comment: 1. I know there are no effects on rpb, it's just prologue and epilogue convention;
2. Ok edited with movl and 32 bit register
3. Yes, sizeof(int) = 4. Thank you!
4. Edited. Should be the same now, but I still used AT&T. :D